# Spring MVC 3.2.4 @RequestMapping don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Try to create restful service with spring mvc, but can't get access to it. After read tons of answers here all seems right, maybe you can see something.

```
21.09.2013 10:50:33 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/book] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                ru.expbrain.flib.config.RestConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.hmtl</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

RestConfig.java

```
package ru.expbrain.flib.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ru.expbrain.flib.rest.controller"})
public class RestConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

BookController.java

```
package ru.expbrain.flib.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import ru.expbrain.flib.rest.entity.Book;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@Controller
public class BookController {

    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value="/book", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Book greeting(@RequestParam(value="content", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Book(counter.incrementAndGet(), name);
    }
}
```

Try to get content over path, btw root context path go to /

```
http://localhost:9080/rest/book
```

Comment: Check logs on your application startup, you should see the dispatcher mapping in details

Comment: Are you sure your `BookController` is getting instantiated? (You can use a `@PostConstruct` method to write a log message.)

Comment: There are no any mention of mapping process, however it's show mvc-dispatcher-servlet initialization

Comment: No there is no messages from @PostConstruct

Comment: What you've posted works for me. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sotirios Delimanolis for testing.

This was some problem with caching... can't explain what happen, because it wasn't repair with cleaning... but recreate the project help and all seems fine.